# CSS vertical align trick of parent not working with percentage img image inside child div

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

As I found out, the best browser friendly solution for vertical aligning is the trick with a pseudo element. But it's not working if I need to use **percentages with image inside another div**.

[Here is a fiddle of my problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/xoks5f1e/4/)

I need to work with percentages due to responsive design.

I realize that the problem is may be caused by the "width" of the pseudo element, because when I change the width of the child element to 99%, it jumps back where it should be, but why is this necessary? I don't want to use 99% as this can cause problems (when shrinking browser window it has to be eventually changed to 98%,97%...) and image is not touching sides of it's parent element. Does anybody know the reason? Thanks.

```css
html, body { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px;
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent:before { 
  content: ""; 
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.child { 
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 25%; 
  width: 100%;
}
img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
      <img src="http://www.resortcollection.com/wp-content/themes/resortcollection/property-images/summit/summit-beach-resort-panama-city-beach-fl-beach-01.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain the outcome you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like the div with the image (`.child`) to be vertically aligned within the parent (`.parent`) element.

Comment: you mean in the center of the parent?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to remove all whitespaces between `parent` and `child` divs, so there is no whitespace between `:before` and `child`. And also you should remember to add `vertical-align` to `child`

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vto7dm0r/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you put the :before pseudo-element in place it goes right at the start of the content, that is, before any spaces. So your horizontal layout is

```
before-pseudo   single-collapsed-Space      img
 Zero width     4px (from the font size)    100% of container
```

Which is too big. Use `margin-left:-4px;` on the pseudo element to compensate.

See https://jsfiddle.net/xoks5f1e/5/

Comment: Why so complicated? You may just skip space before `img` tag

Comment: @DenisSheremet - I don't follow. Can you provide a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: @Alohci Seems it's magically working. But are you sure about the 4px? I mean... I'm making layout with percentages and you are suggesting absolute units. What this 4 pixels really mean and more importantly, what affects it?

Comment: @DenisSheremet - You mean making it `<div class="child"><img src...`? That does not work unfortunatelly as I can say.

Comment: @MartinL.- the 4px is based on the width of the glyph in the font that's being used for the space character at the current font-size, plus any letter-spacing that may be in place. So if the font was say "Courier New", 4px wouldn't be sufficient. But you almost always know what font-family, font-size and letter-spacing you're using, so it's generally possible to pick a suitable number, or if necessary calc() function to compensate for the space.

Comment: I'm surprised someone downvoted this answer! @ downvoter I can't see any reason why you down voted here...

Comment: @Alohci - hmmm and that's the problem. What if the font won't load properly (I'm using Google fonts, so it might happen) and browser will use an alternative. What I mean is that I can't be sure about the width of the glyph, can I? And because of that this solution - even though it's nice, simple and working - is a bit unreliable. I just don't know how much I can trust it and whether I should built up my layout on this. In addition `calc` is unfortunatelly not that well supported by older browsers. But anyways thank you so much for help!

Comment: So basically @DenisSheremet was offering the most cleanest solution, I just did not fully understand earlier. So thanks. :)

Comment: @MartinL. Fair enough. My primary goal was to explain the reason why the "trick" wasn't working. The removal and hiding of spaces between inline and inline-block elements is discussed at length in many SO questions. There's a number of approaches available depending on the exact circumstances, and there's much merit in just removing the spaces between the tags as per your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest my own solution that I've mysteriously did not see earlier. It is a solution that most of professional webdesigners use. And that is to remove the space/line-break between tags styled with `display: inline-block`.

> **Important note**: When applying `::before` pseudo element on some parent element (e.g. `.parent`), CSS will append this new pseudo element directly "before" the first child element of the node `.parent`. That means if the first child element of `.parent` is separated from the opening `.parent` tag by a new paragraph character or a space, then this white space character will also be before the newly appended pseudo element. And because of that, when using `display: inline-block` the white-space character will also affect CSS's pseudo element.

The solution in case you have the access to the HTML file, is:

1. First child of `.parent` must be directly after `.parent`'s opening tag as **@DenisSheremet** suggested.
2. Make a real element instead of "pseudo" one in real DOM:

   ```
   <div style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle"></div><
   div class="child">
   ```

   or more elegantly using comments:

   ```
   <div style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle"></div><!--
   --><div class="child">
   ```

If you have only access to CSS, than the only other choice what I know so far is the solution suggested by **@Alohci** to remove the white space with default font space width of 4px, using negative margin.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoks5f1e/6/)